# Read MySQL JSON datatype and cast it into List<Int> in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, json, list, varchar

I am trying to return a list of numbers from mysql database which has JSON datatype in the table.

the mysql.connector in c# thinks the datatype is VARCHAR so basically I get in return "[1, 2, 3]" from the database.

I need to cast the string return into List<*INT*> so I can work with it directly.

to be more specific, that's what I get from the mysql reader

```
string mylist = "[1, 2, 3]"
```

and I want to cast it into

```
List<Int> mylist_int = [1, 2, 3]
```

So if there is a way to read JSON datatype from the database directly in JSON format that would be great.

alternatively I am looking for a way to parse the string list and convert it into c# native list.

Thank you,

Comment: A `List<int>` isn't JSON. It's something produced after *parsing* JSON. JSON has arrays, not lists too. Assuming MySQL Connector returns a JSON type it will still need some kind of transformation before it becomes a `List<int>`

Comment: How do you read this result? MySql/Connector.NET doesn't just think JSON is a string, [it *explicitly* reads it as a string and returns a MySqlString](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data/Field.cs#L377). You can parse this using Json.NET, arguably the most popular JSON serializer in .NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I basically have a reader object and after running the mysql command and I am using Reader.GetValue(int column number) to get the data.

Comment: `GetValue()` will return whatever the underlying type is. It doesn't perform any kind of parsing. That's explicitly specified to be a string, in the linked source code

Comment: you are right, there is other `GetValue(), GetInt64(), etc..` functions but there is nothing for JSON. and when I checked `GetDataType()` it returned VARCHAR. which as you said will be a string in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a JSON parser like [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the JSON string, eg :

```
var json=reader.GetString(0);
//Returns a List<int>
var myList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json);
```

or

```
var jsonArray=JArray.Parse(json);
```

MySQL Connector [explicitly treats JSON as a string](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data/Field.cs#L377), it doesn't "think" they are text :

```
    case MySqlDbType.Set:
    case MySqlDbType.Enum:
    case MySqlDbType.String:
    case MySqlDbType.VarString:
    case MySqlDbType.VarChar:
    case MySqlDbType.Text:
    case MySqlDbType.TinyText:
    case MySqlDbType.MediumText:
    case MySqlDbType.LongText:
    case MySqlDbType.JSON:
    case (MySqlDbType)Field_Type.NULL:
      return new MySqlString(type, true);
```

The library's own [tests use `GetString()` to read JSON data](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/68c54371821c87ff40a773acc127ce357b46a5ae/Tests/MySql.Data.Tests/DataTypeTests.cs#L1297) :

```
[Fact]
public void CanReadJsonValue()
{
  ...
  using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    Assert.True(reader.Read());
    Assert.Equal("[\"a\", {\"b\": [true, false]}, [10, 20]]", reader.GetString(0));
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `JSON.NET` did the job. 

Answer (score -1):

you could use `List<dynamic>`. you can call all the functions you can with `List<int>`. the only problem is, you won't be able to see them because of dynamic, but it will work.

Comment: What will work? How can you make MySQL Connector/.NET return a List of whatever when there's no such method in the data reader?

Comment: sorry didn't get the question that well. but if you want your list of strings to a list of integers you could use `List<int> yourIntList = youStringList.Select(int.Parse).ToList()`

Comment: I did use this way at first but then the data should be saved as "1, 2, 3" in the database not "[1, 2, 3]" because even brackets are treated as numbers which raise an error. I think dealing with the value as a string is not the best fit from the first place. there should be something for serializing and deserializing JSON datatypes from the mysql connector.

Comment: There's no list of strings, only a JSON string that needs parsing

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to parse the [1,2,3,4] value from the database into a List

```
    private static List<int> ParseDbInt(string databaseValue)
    {
        // Remove brackets
        var numStr = databaseValue.Replace("[", String.Empty);
        numStr     = numStr.Replace("]", String.Empty);

        // Now split that string into a string array using String.Split
        var numbers = numStr.Split(new char[] { ',' });

        // Split the comma-seperated numbers into a List using LINQ "Select" keyword
        return new List<int>(numbers.Select(s => int.Parse(s)));
    }
```